# Как помощью pandas перевести все поля DataFrame в строковый тип данных?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть двумерный датафрейм X, `X.shape = (N, M)`.
При использовании `X.apply(str)` в строковый тип данных переводятся столбцы целиком, и в результате остается одномерный датафрейм Nx1.
Как применять функцию `str` к каждому полю таблицы, а не по столбцам?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы привести все столбцы к строковому типу данных можно воспользоваться [DataFrame.astype()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
X = X.astype(str)
```